# PHP get variable in a function for another action

Tags: php

I have read another topics but I couldn't apply the other answer to my code :S

I have this function

```
function add_image($cFile) {

    //SET SETTINGS FOR THE IMAGE
    $target_dir = "../images/cuisines/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["cImage"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $cFile = basename($_FILES["cImage"]["name"], '.'. $imageFileType).uniqid($prefix = '-', $more_entropy = null) .'.'. $imageFileType;

    //BUT FIRST CHECK IF THERE IS NOT FILE
    if ($_FILES['cImage']['size'] == 0) {       
        echo "<script>alert('You forgot the image, you must complete the form again');</script>" ;
        echo '<script>window.location="'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] .'"</script>' ;
        exit();
    } 

    // CHECK IF THE FILE IS AN IMAGE
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["cImage"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check == false) {
        echo "<script>alert('This is not an Image, you must complete the form again');</script>" ;
        echo '<script>window.location="'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] .'"</script>' ;
        exit();
    }

    //ALLOW CERTAIN KIND OF FILES
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "<script>alert('Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed, you must complete the form again');</script>" ;
        echo '<script>window.location="'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] .'"</script>' ;
        exit();
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cImage"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$cFile)) { 
        return $cFile;
        } else {
return false;
}

    }
```

And then if the function is succesfull I want to do this:

```
if (add_image($cFile) !== false) {

        echo $cfile;
}
```

Can someone help me to know what I am doing wrong? I have read similar topics but I couldn't use them in my case.

The error I receive is about the variable cFile in the second part of code doesn't exist :S

Comment: are these in the same file?

Comment: You're saying the `$cFile` in `if (add_image($cFile))` doesn't exist? Well, we can't tell you why, since we don't see anything before that line.

Comment: yes same file! say undefined... I want to pass the variable in the function to the other action

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks like it terminates the whole script if it fails, so the only way you can reach the bottom code is if the function was successful.

You probably don't need the `if` statement.

An approach that would probably be better is to `return false;` if the function failed, and then check `if (add_image($cFile) !== false)`

Comment: the problem is I can not get the variable cFile in the query

Answer (score 0):

May be $target_dir, may not have write access permission. If not add write permission for target_dir using chmod command.

Comment: the function is succesfull, I can not pass the variable cFile to the query

Comment: if (add_image($cFile)) replace this code with bellow code:

$cFile=add_image($cFile);
if(isset($cFile)||!empty($cFile)){
//
}